# Import/Export sheet from excel 2003 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, export, excel-2003

Need to export and import a sheet from my workbook using VBA.

What's the easier way to do it?

Export as CSV?

Export as txt?

Can I save the object (the copy/paste object) to a file and then import that object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about exporting into a new XLS, just containing that sheet? That would be the easiest the solution, preserving not only contents but also formatting of that sheet.

For getting some initial VBA code, just use the macro recorder and record the commands when you do this manually - "New Document", Right-Click on sheet name, "Copy sheet to new document", and for the import "Open existing document", Right-Click on sheet name, "Copy sheet into existing document".

For example, copying a sheet to a new workbook:

```
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
set newWb =Workbooks.Add()
wb.ActiveSheet.Copy newWb.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: thnx great idea (macro recording), I don't need to preserv the formating (there's none) but it seems easier this way